# Combobox values from array are not shown in 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba, filter, combobox

I have a weird issue in that my combobox is displaying the contents of an array on top of each other rather than displaying in 2 columns. The image below shows the results:

[image]

My code below basically gets me the right results but the results im expecting should be:

F106612 M2500 E4X GA

Here is my code:

```
    Public Sub ComboBox4_DropButtonClick()

           If Range("AA1").Value = "RoutineCompleted" Then
  
           RunRoutine.Enabled = False

           Dim rCell As Range, ws As Worksheet, arr

           Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
           ComboBox4.ColumnCount = 2

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
       For Each rCell In ws.Range("N3", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp))
         If Not .Exists(rCell.Value) And rCell.Offset(0, -11).Value = 1 And rCell.Value <> "" Then
            .Add rCell, rCell.Offset(0, -3).Value 
       End If
    Next rCell
    arr = Application.Transpose(Array(.Keys, .items)) 

        End With

    With ComboBox4
       .ColumnCount = 2 'set number of columns to be shown
       .List = arr      'put the array in the list property
    End With

   End If


    End Sub
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Thankyou

Comment: `arr = Application.Transpose(Array(.Keys, .items))` this likely doesn't do what you think it does: it just creates an array of arrays.  You'll need to loop over those two arrays and combine them into a single 2D array.

Comment: Thanks Tim, to be honest all I want to do which I have working is getting all unique values in a column and just show its associated description in the 2nd column. What do I need to look into to resolve this do you think buddy?

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```vb
Public Sub ComboBox4_DropButtonClick()

    Dim rCell As Range, ws As Worksheet, dict
    
    If Range("AA1").Value = "RoutineCompleted" Then
    
        RunRoutine.Enabled = False
        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ComboBox4.ColumnCount = 2
    
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        For Each rCell In ws.Range("N3", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp))
            If Not dict.Exists(rCell.Value) And _
                       rCell.Offset(0, -11).Value = 1 And _
                       rCell.Value <> "" Then
                dict.Add rCell, rCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
            End If
        Next rCell
        
        If dict.Count > 0 Then
            With ComboBox4
                .ColumnCount = 2 'set number of columns to be shown
                .List = DictToArray(dict)      'put the array in the list property
            End With
        Else
            '???
        End If
        
    End If 'routine completed
End Sub

'convert dictionary to 2D array
Function DictToArray(dict As Object)
    Dim arr, k, i As Long
    i = 0
    ReDim arr(0 To dict.Count - 1, 0 To 1)
    For Each k In dict.keys
        arr(i, 0) = k
        arr(i, 1) = dict(k)
        i = i + 1
    Next k
    DictToArray = arr
End Function
```